# /etc/fstab equivalent in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, mount

There's a file called `/etc/fstab` in Linux OS. It is a configuration file that contains information of all the partitions and storage devices in the computer. Basically it contains the mount information. So, my question is, is there a similar file in Windows OS that contains the mount information? If so, where is it located?

Comment: %systemroot%\system32\CONFIG\SYSTEM. Then there are several type of entries under HKLM\system.

Answer (score 10):

> It is a configuration file that contains information of all the partitions and storage devices in the computer.

No, it isn't.  It's a configuration database for the `mount` command to consult, which may contain information about partitions and devices that don't even currently exist, and which may conversely not list things that do exist.  It is, in essence, merely a way of supplying the filling for the blanks when one doesn't give all of the instructions explicity to the `mount` command.

The files that contain all of the actual mount information on Linux are `/etc/mtab` (an ordinary file maintained by the `mount` and `umount` programs themselves) and `/proc/mounts` (a file maintained by the kernel that reports the actual system state).

There's no equivalent to `/etc/fstab` in Windows NT because **Windows NT does not work that way**.  Mounting volumes is not done by running a `mount` command.  Nor is assigning a drive letter (which is done via a symbolic link in the Object Manager under `\DosDevices`) the same as mounting.

Assignation of a drive letter is done by [associating a drive letter with an already mounted volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff560457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Mounting is a process that involves sending [a notification to a filesystem driver to mount itself on the volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff548670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  By the time that Windows NT gets to assigning a drive letter, it has often *already mounted* the volume.  Mounting doesn't need user commands in order to happen.  It's done in kernel mode as part of Plug and Play.  The disc device driver tells the [volume manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb540532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whenever a new disc comes along.  The volume manager creates new mountable volumes (from information contained in the partition tables, LDM database, or elsewhere) for the individual or combined slices of such a disc.  And the I/O manager mounts the volumes so created, trying each filesystem driver in turn, after that.

There's no configuration file for the `mount` command, because **there isn't a `mount` command**.  Windows NT does not work that way.

Comment: I'm not done reading all the links, but I must say, this is a well effort answer.

Comment: @JdeBP: I don't understand this **there isn't a mount command**. I use the `mountvol` command for mounting and un-mounting an existing file system. Am I missing something here? Please let me know. I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: The `mountvol` command doesn't do what a POSIX `mount` command does.  `mountvol` operates, again, upon _already mounted volumes_.  The giveaway is that _one names the already mounted volume_ as a parameter to the command.

Answer (score 3):

Drive letter assignments are kept in the Registry, under `HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`, while filesystem mounts (Unix-style) are stored on the filesystem itself, as NTFS "junctions".

You can edit this information using `mountvol` or `diskpart` from command line, or `diskmgmt.msc` GUI. Do *not* edit the registry directly.

Comment: HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices is only for the Win32/Win64 subsystems. The native part use other directories.