# Stop Windows from mounting a NTFS file system

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, filesystems, multi-boot

I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, and I recently decided to experiment with gaming on Linux.  It works quite well for most of the games I try.  However, for some reason, some of the games demand to be on an NTFS file system.  This wouldn't be a problem, except Windows automatically mounts all NTFS file systems it sees and won't let them go without turning off hibernate.

I don't want Windows to see or touch the partition, but I do have another partition on the same drive that Windows has to see.  Is there a way I can get Windows to ignore a specific partition?

Comment: I should note that I managed to stop Windows from assigning it a drive letter and stop the user from being able to see it, but Windows is still mounting it, so Ubuntu can't mount it.

Comment: Mac & nix use `fstab` which Win doesn't seem to have an equivalent of - maybe this could be useful for ref… https://superuser.com/questions/338969/etc-fstab-equivalent-in-windows

Comment: Is the partition on a GPT disk?

Comment: The partition is on a GPT disk

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you saying this can't be done in Windows?  Because that is very annoying if it is the case.  One of my main use cases for using and Ubuntu partition for games is being able to hibernate Windows with work stuff open and not have to worry about resources.

Comment: tbh, I'm saying I don't know enough about it - I just googled 'fstab windows' to see if it had a similar implementation to the one I do know about.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fstab equivalent on Windows is the "Mount Manager", which you control via DiskMgmt.msc, or DISKPART, or the MOUNTVOL command.

It may be enough to remove the drive letter, either via DiskMgmt.msc, or using `remove` within DISKPART. Additionally you can set the GPT attribute field to "No automount" (bit 63) to prevent the partition from ever automatically receiving a drive letter.

If that still doesn't help, set the GPT attribute "Hidden" (bit 62) to make the Mount Manager completely ignore this partition, and/or "Read-only" (bit 60) to tell Windows it should be read-only.

If *that* doesn't help, change the partition's GPT type GUID to something else than "Microsoft Basic Data". For example, use one of the Linux partition types.

(All of the above are completely ignored by Linux and will not prevent you from using the partition.)

**Windows (DiskPart)**

1. Use `list disk` and `sel disk <num>` to select the physical disk.
2. Use `list part` and `sel part <num>` to select the partition you want to change.
3. Use `remove` to unassign the current drive letter.
4. Set GPT attributes to "Hidden" using `gpt attributes=0x4000000000000000`.

   - No automount = 0x8000000000000000
   - Hidden = 0x4000000000000000
   - Read-only = 0x1000000000000000
   - all of the above = 0xD000000000000000

**Linux (sfdisk)**

sfdisk takes a comma-separated list of bits to set:

```
sfdisk --part-attrs /dev/sda <partnum> 63
```

For "Microsoft Basic Data" partitions, bit 63 is "No GPTautomount"; bit 62 is "Hidden"; bit 60 is "Read-only".

**Linux (gdisk)**

Run `gdisk /dev/sda`.

- To change partition type GUID: Use `t` and choose whatever type looks least Windows-friendly.
- To change partition flags: Use `x` to enter "Expert" menu, then `a` to select "Set attributes". Enter partition number and enable bits 60/62/63. Afterwards use `m` to return to the main menu.

Don't forget to use `w` to write the updated partition table.

Comment: The DiskPart worked like a charm!  I have a hibernated Windows and Linux can mount the drive.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it only worked for one day.  Now it doesn't seem to be working anymore, and I am getting messages about it being a mounted partition again.