# How to stop win from mounting / accessing other NTFS partition?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, ntfs

**A little about my dual boot setup :**

I am currently dual booting win 10 and win 8.1 .They both are on same disk. Whenever I boot an option shows up in windows bootloader - to select which one to boot . Something like this -

[image]

**My problem (basically what I am trying to do)**

I want win 10 c drive completely inaccessible from win 8.1 . If that is not possible then at least it's mounted in read only mode.

**What I have tried/found out :**

1.[stop-windows-from-mounting-a-ntfs-file-system](https://superuser.com/questions/1469888/stop-windows-from-mounting-a-ntfs-file-system)

*Am afraid messing with attributes as suggested in this answer because it will create a huge problem when I will try to boot from windows 10*

2.[how-to-make-a-partition-on-external-storage-read-only-and-revert-to-normal](https://superuser.com/questions/236786/how-to-make-a-partition-on-external-storage-read-only-and-revert-to-normal)

Same as above, suggests a attribute change

Comment: You might be able to encrypt win10 with bit locker.  Windows 8 might ask for the password, but just click cancel.

Comment: While booted into W8, go to disk management and delete the drive letter for the W10 partition. This will remove it being mounted in windows explorer, which should help you with specific issues (which you did not state).